# swift dependency in objc podspec project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I'm creating my first CocoaPod project (ObjC) which requires a Swift dependency. When I try to lint the project I get the error:

> Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it.

I understand how to do this when including a CocoaPod in a regular xcode project, but how do I solve this issue when the project is a CocoaPod? I tried adding the 'use_frameworks!' declaration in the podspec file but that doesn't seem to be correct.

Here is my podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name             = "my-custom-pod"
  s.version          = "0.0.1"
  s.summary          = "totally awesome stuff"

  s.description      = <<-DESC
                         more details about the totally awesome stuff, if only it worked :(
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = "https://awesomestuff.com"
  # s.screenshots     = "www.example.com/screenshots_1", "www.example.com/screenshots_2"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "Me" => "me@awesomestuff.com" }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://awesome.com/awesome/my-custom-pod.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/awesomestuff'

  s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'my-custom-pod' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  s.frameworks = 'CoreLocation', 'MapKit'
  s.dependency 'SSKeychain', '~> 1.2.3'
  s.dependency 'FMDB', '~> 2.5'
  s.dependency 'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.10.4'
  s.dependency 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 4.0.4'
end
```

Here, the socket io client is the issue. I'm able to import the socket io framework into my other ObjC projects no problem, but I've never tried to do it into a custom cocoa pod.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`use_frameworks!` is a podfile-only setting.

The way to use frameworks while linting a podspec is to provide the `--use-frameworks` flag to your `pod spec lint` command.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @pevasquez ! I was using the --use-frameworks flag when linting because I was also using the GoogleMaps framework, but I was still getting the error related to the Socket IO framework being Swift.

Comment: Correction, `--use-frameworks` is not a valid lint command. `--use-libraries` is perhaps what you were referring to? That doesn't seem to fix the issue though; again, I was using that previously due to the GoogleMaps dependency.

Comment: Well, you're right, ```--use-frameworks``` is no more a flag for lint, as it's the default behavior now. ```--use-libraries``` means just the opposite to that, so try without it and see how you go. No Swift dependency wil work with that flag

Comment: Thanks again, pevasquez. That was part of the issue. Will summarize below.

Answer (score 1):

Add in podsepc file :-

```
spec.dependency 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '12.0.0'

  spec.pod_target_xcconfig   = {

    'SWIFT_VERSION' => '4.0',
    'VALID_ARCHS' => 'x86_64 arm64'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The lint was failing because I was trying to include the --use-libraries lint command to accommodate the GoogleMaps pod but this is not compatible when trying to include a swift pod like Socket.IO. Because the GoogleMaps pod includes a static version of itself within the pod you cannot simply include it in your pod project otherwise you get the lint error `The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries`

So I ended up having to grab the GoogleMaps.framework and include it statically in my pod (as opposed to listing the pod as a dependency). Not ideal but I can't find another working solution to include both a swift pod and the GoogleMaps pod.

Here are the relevant bits from my podspec file:

```
s.libraries = 'c++', 'icucore', 'z'

s.dependency 'SSKeychain', '~> 1.2.3'
s.dependency 'FMDB', '~> 2.5'
s.dependency 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 5.3.3'

s.frameworks = 'MapKit', 'GoogleMaps', 'AVFoundation', 'CoreData','CoreLocation', 'CoreText', 'GLKit', 'ImageIO', 'OpenGLES', 'QuartzCore', 'SystemConfiguration', 'Accelerate'
s.resource_bundles = { 'GoogleMaps' => ['Pod/Dependencies/GoogleMaps.framework/Resources/*.bundle'] }
s.vendored_frameworks = 'Pod/Dependencies/GoogleMaps.framework'
s.xcconfig = { 'LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS' => 'Pod/Dependencies' }
```

And here is the lint command that works with this podspec:

`pod lib lint my-custom-pod.podspec --private --allow-warnings`

The only issue I'm seeing now is when I import the pod into my project I'm either stuck with this warning prior to runtime:

> Auto-Linking supplied 'path/to/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps', framework linker option at path/to/Pod/Dependencies/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps is not a dylib

Or this one at compile time (shows in console):

> Class GMSBillingPointRecorder is implemented in both path/to/my/application/Frameworks/my-custom-pod.framework/my-custom-pod and path/to/my/app/myapp.app/myapp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Where there is a separate console log warning like this for every Class in the GoogleMaps framework. I cannot seem to get rid of these warnings. If I link I get a warning, if I don't link I get warnings.